# How many rows will be locked at worst in a table whose engine is InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb

MySQL Community Server, Server version: 5.6.24

```
mysql> show create table user\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: user
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_number` (`number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM user;
+--------+
| number |
+--------+
|     10 |
|     11 |
|     12 |
|     13 |
|     14 |
|     14 |
+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The engine of table `user` is InnoDB.

**Question 1:**

When execute the following statement:

```
select * from user where number = 10 for update;
```

, how many rows will be locked **at worst** ? More than one rows ?

**Question 2:**

When execute the following statement:

```
select * from user where number = 14 for update;
```

, how many rows will be locked **at worst** ? More than two rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the field is indexed so in case of INNODB

**Answer 1**

only 1 row locked.

**Answer 2**

only 2 rows locked.

Answer (score 0):

as this field is indexed so in first case only single row will be blocked and in 2nd case 2 rows as innodb used row level locking based on index.